# Reading the network requests of a given URL using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I need to get the URL in red using python, it changes every day so I can't just hardcode it into my program, the only fixed URL that I have is the one in green, GET parameters like token, qid, or callback change every day so I can't request it directly
[image: GreenLinkisFixed RedLinkchanges]

Is there a way to get a list of all the "Network" requests? if I can get that I can then look for the URL I need using the part that doesn't change or a way to get directly the link to the .JSON either is fine, how can I achieve this?

EDIT:
I have this fixed link https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities?sc_lang=en (green) and need this link https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityfilter?lang=eng&token=evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeGwzK35ZFJ/ZUHtaMT29Z5aJ1PmQCIZMQ2aoTplY9Ozc3&sort=5&order=0&qid=1627532414377&callback=jQuery35109210633367295534_1627532407574&_=1627532407576 (red)
the problem is that the red link changes every day as well as its GET parameters so I need to extract it using the green link, I have already tried getting the HTML using `requests` and `urllib3` but the HTML has none of the information of either the new GET parameters nor the info contained in the .JSON

EDIT2: I have NO problem with this part, but here is where I can't hardcode the red URL

```
url='https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityfilter?lang=eng&token=evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeG9L82ZzJ20aOxX0Y6tf3oVlc%2f2L6sWNlm1qsCGs3dLts&sort=5&order=0&qid=1627389214442&callback=jQuery351020345220954587373_1627389204429&_=1627389204431'
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
data = data['data']
...print...
```

Comment: Please provide information in text form rather then in image. Also provide your effort!

Comment: @Xitiz I have added a description and some of the things I've tried, thx

Comment: Please try to _"it changes every day so I can't just hardcode it into my program"_ add your code/program as well. :)

Comment: @Xitiz I added the part that "I can't hardcode", I don't think it's of any vital information for the problem but I hope it helps

Comment: I just wanted to see, you have done enough effort to solve your problem by yourself. Have you found any pattern in that red link, like I found that there they use date as `_` as underscore parameters and `qid` as well. Can you provide that link from other different dates also? And you are trying to get that link only or that link from different dates?

Comment: @Xitiz the link in my EDIT2 is from today, I have the one from yesterday "https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityfilter?lang=eng&token=evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeG9L82ZzJ20aOxX0Y6tf3oVlc%2f2L6sWNlm1qsCGs3dLts&sort=5&order=0&qid=1627389214442&callback=jQuery351020345220954587373_1627389204429&_=1627389204431" it is no longer valid, I have been keeping track of token,callback and qid for the las 3 days in search of pattern but there is none, that's why I'm going with getting it directly from the network request

Comment: Looking at the 'Initiator' sub-tab in the network tab in chrome led me to the this js file which generates the token : https://www.hkex.com.hk/lhkexw/js/equities.js?_=20180716a
regarding the qid, I assume it is generated somewhere else or in the same file, I hope it is a good lead for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this question:

- How to do this: there are several libraries in Python which let you access websites as though you were browsing, with varying degrees of fidelity, up to and including running the actual browser in the background and controlling it from Python (for example, selenium). That last will definitely work, although it's quite annoying as well as fragile - it'll break every time the stock exchange changes the website layout significantly.
- The stock exchange sells this data by subscription (both directly and via resellers like Reuters or Morningstar). This has two consequences:

  - Reading the data with a subscription will be much easier; there will be a documented API, possibly example code, tech support.
  - Without a subscription, they may be quite annoyed at you trying to scrape the information and take active steps to stop you (technical or potentially legal).